# Facebook unable to live mode

Tags: facebook-login

I wanted to use Facebook Login to my website and unfortunately throws me error saying:

```
App not set up: This app is still in development mode, and you don't have access to it. Switch 
to a registered test user or ask an app admin for permissions.
```

I've read some discussions that the app should be set from `In Development` to `Live Mode`, so I tried. However, switching to `Live Mode` requires me to provide my terms and privacy URL and I did provide the URL`(https://example.com/terms-of-service`, however I still cannot switch to Live mode.

While reading some docs, it says to check my URL for some errors using FB's tool https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

now I noticed I was missing some `og meta tags`, so I added this block of code in the `<head>` of my `index.html` like this:

```
<!-- og tags -->
<meta property="og:url"                content="https://example.com" />
<meta property="og:type"               content="website" />
<meta property="og:title"              content="Site's placeholder title" />
<meta property="og:description"        content="Site's placeholder description" />
<meta property="og:image"              content="https://mystoragebucket/mysiteimage.png" />
<meta property="fb:app_id"             content="my_fb_app_id" />
```

and re-`scrape` the URL again. and for a brief sigh of relief, it was successful and didn't show me any errors and warnings.

Howevere, I still cannot switch to `Live Mode`. it still says :

```
Before switching to live mode, you must provide both a valid Privacy 
Policy URL and data deletion information. Update this information in 
Basic Settings on App Dashboard
```

Any idea on what I am missing here?
Facebook Login is quite annoying really.

Answer (score 1):

And yet again, posting my problem on SO helps me solve my own problem x100.

For those who encounters the same issue, please read carefully like I didn't.

```
Data Deletion Callback URL
```

is the missing part. just add some URL and voila, your good to go.